# window.scroll() not scrolling on iOS and it barely moving

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, scroll

I have a main content (`<main>` tag) area, and an arrow absolutely positioned at the bottom that should scroll down the height of the page (`window.innerHeight`). On Desktop it works perfectly fine, but on Mobile, it barely moves, like maybe 10 pixels. I realized that you can't use the `behavior` property with the options so I removed it and am now using `window.scroll(0, window.innerHeight)`. I've checked that `window.innerHeight` is returning the right value, so it's not that.

This is my HTML:

```
<main>
    <header>
        <img src="../assets/Logo.svg" alt="Personal Logo" style="height: 20vh;">
        <h1>Sup Gamers</h1>
    </header>
    <aside class="about">
        <section></section>
        <button class="btn" tabindex="0"><i class="material-icons">arrow_forward_ios
        </i></button>
    </aside>
    <aside class="skills">
        <button class="btn" tabindex="0"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back_ios_new
        </i></button>
        <section></section>
    </aside>
    <div class="downarrow" tabindex="0"><i class="material-icons md-48">expand_more</i></div>
    <section class="projects">
        <button class="uparrow" title="View Projects"><i class="material-icons md-48">expand_less</i></button>
        <button id="add-item">Add Item</button>
        <div class='project-grid'>

        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

And my CSS that pertains to the elements:

```
main {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('../assets/home-background.jpg');
background-size: cover;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column ;
}

main header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

aside {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    transition: all 0.65s ease-out;
}

aside > section {
    width: 97%;
}

aside > .btn {
    width: 3%;
    background: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    transition: background 0.3s linear;
}

aside > .btn:hover {
    background:#202C39;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.about {
    transform: translateX(-97vw);
    left: 0;
}

.about section {
    background: #998888;
}


.skills {
    transform: translateX(97vw);
    right: 0;
}

.skills section {
   background: #640D14; 
}

.moveIn {
    transform: translateX(0);
    z-index: 2;
}

.moveIn > div > i {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.about.moveIn {
    background: #998888;
}

.skills.moveIn {
    background: #640D14;
}

.downarrow {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
}

.projects {
    transform: translateY(100Vh);
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #005fc5;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.uparrow {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.project-grid {
    bordeR: 1px solid red;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    align-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.project-item {
    width: 30%;
    height:30vh;
    background: white;
    margin: 1.25%;
}
```

And My JS:

```
const about = document.querySelector('.about')
const skills = document.querySelector('.skills')
const downarrow = document.querySelector('.downarrow')
const uparrow = document.querySelector('.uparrow')

var aboutToggled = false
var skillsToggled = false;

if (!!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform)) {
    document.querySelector('header > h1').innerHTML = 'Mobile'
} else {
    document.querySelector('header > h1').innerHTML = 'Not Mobile'
}

console.log(window.innerHeight)

about.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!aboutToggled) {
        about.classList.add('moveIn')
    } else {
        about.classList.remove('moveIn')
    }
    aboutToggled = !aboutToggled;
})

skills.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!skillsToggled) {
        skills.classList.add('moveIn')
    } else {
        skills.classList.remove('moveIn')
    }
    skillsToggled = !skillsToggled
})

downarrow.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!(!!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform))) {
        window.scroll({
            top: window.innerHeight,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    } else {
        window.scroll(0, screen.height)
        console.log('Scrolling On Mobile')
    }
    about.tabIndex = -1;
    skills.tabIndex = -1;
    downarrow.tabIndex = -1;
    uparrow.tabIndex = 0;
})

uparrow.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!(!!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform))) {
        window.scroll({
            top: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    } else {
        window.scroll(0, screen.height)
        console.log('Scrolling On Mobile')   
    }
    about.tabIndex = 0;
    skills.tabIndex = 0;
    downarrow.tabIndex = 0;
    uparrow.tabIndex = -1;
})

var num = 0;
document.querySelector('#add-item').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let newItem = document.createElement('div')
    newItem.innerText = num
    num++
    newItem.classList.add('project-item')
    document.querySelector('.project-grid').append(newItem)
})
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there room to scroll? It looks like there is minimal HTML. If the browser window has reached the bottom of the page it can't scroll any further. As a check could you add many `<br />` to the bottom of the page and see if it can scroll to your element?

Comment: There is one element that is 100vh tall and another that is 100vh as well. It can scroll perfectly fine in desktop, just not mobile